# Connecting Postgres to older Android (7.1.1) Failed resolution of: Ljavax/security/sasl/SaslException

Tags: java, android, postgresql, database-connection

I run this app on Android 13 and everything is ok but i need run this on Android 7.1.1.

Logcat:
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.exception.ScramInvalidServerSignatureException>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/security/sasl/SaslException;

MainActivity.java:

Imports

````
package com.example.connecttest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;    ```
````

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private final String host1 = "10.0.2.2";
private final String database1 = "test";
private final int port1 = 5432;
private final String user1 = "postgres";
private  final String pass1 = "password123";
private  String url1 = "jdbc:postgresql://%s:%d/%s";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView edt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
    Button btnget=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView txv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btnget.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Connection connection =conclass();
            txv.setText("1");
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    txv.setText("2");
                    String sqlquery = "Select * from person where id='" + edt.getText().toString() + "'";

                    Statement st = connection.createStatement();

                    ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(sqlquery);

                    txv.setText("brak");
                    while(resultSet.next()){
                        txv.setText((resultSet.getString(2)));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e("Error ", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection conclass(){
    Connection con = null;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tp= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);

    try {
        this.url1 = String.format(this.url1, this.host1, this.port1, this.database1);
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user1, pass1);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    }
    return con;

}
```

}

```
I'm stuck here and anyone can help to have a look?
```